Manually fetching Authorization code and Access token using postman
I have created a springboot application implementing oauth2 using github. I was trying to generate authorization code and access token using postman. I am able to get the authorization code but while trying to generate access token in facing issues. please guide me on this.
I am tried to generate access token but getting response as bad request or bad_verification_code.
I have hit the below curl in postman
curl :-
curl --location 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token' \
--header 'Accept:  application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: _gh_sess=qPcgFBJTeJ4a3IrFjKW6p6ub7U%2BaKRflGVfABG4Owuz4%2F7z1tNyog5zFedfmrd63pXM%2BfHRfJzYGh1bRp5BWPhIAHhWsWDCu0f%2Fpr2cbvrrRBPh9ONusrwIFubMIF%2B1DEz3u2R3i4%2FO4aSlG72L9gVVWzCiT3x2XTw9gKCIAkuiWgJ6R8nMzlTMrLyIiVAaKNS0Zb4YvHFuuYbmLzv%2BtyBUy4x4drAnQlBx8VcRTdsjXy1OdqXs%2FE%2BqNTr4yb%2FxWwb3dsZQ8ZZE4CGXWSsE%2FTA%3D%3D--%2FvBzXAeRW6AKFaA7--6Z6xXIag7415cYJx5js0Zg%3D%3D; _octo=GH1.1.1139190396.1730486088; logged_in=no' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=Ov23liS7xf6PU5nLgNt6' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=000ab99bcd49281f031fabfe3934caca12054ff7' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/github' \
--data-urlencode 'code=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'


The Authorization code flow generally requires user/browser interaction to return the code before it can be used to request the access token.  This generally  can't be done in the scripts within Postman which is why the Postman Authorization helpders (the auth tab) exists.  It will open the browser so that the user can enter their credentials before coming back to Postman.  You need to have the Postman client set as the redirect uri.  TLDR.  Not sure you can do this manually in Postman which is why the auth helpers exist.
